# BigQuery: Cast INT64 to BYTES (or binary representation)

Tags: casting, google-bigquery

How can I see the binary representation of an INT64 in BigQuery? Casting it to the BYTES type would also work.

Comment: It's an implementation detail as to whether `INT64` is represented in little-endian or big-endian format. Why does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Elliot Brossard, it is a matter of implementation how the `INT64` type is represented.

Moreover, having a look at [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conversion-rules), you will be able to see the available conversion types in BigQuery. `INT64` can only cast to `BOOL`, `FLOAT64`, `INT64` and `STRING`.

If you really need the Bytes or Binary representation of an integer value in BigQuery, you will have to either pre-process it programatically and add a new column containing those values, or post-process it programatically when you retrieve your data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the `ToHex` UDF shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51600210/4966331

Then pass the string output by that UDF to BigQuery's builtin [FROM_HEX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#from_hex)

For example, this command:

```
bq --location US query \
  --nouse_legacy_sql \
'
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ToHex(x INT64) AS (
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT("%02x", x >> (byte * 8) & 0xff), "" ORDER BY byte DESC)
   FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 7)) AS byte)
);

SELECT
  FROM_HEX(ToHex(1)) = b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01",
  FROM_HEX(ToHex(2)) = b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02",
  FROM_HEX(ToHex(256)) = b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00",
'
```

returns:

```
+------+------+------+
| f0_  | f1_  | f2_  |
+------+------+------+
| true | true | true |
+------+------+------+
```